# Maximize expected heads with biased coins.

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have n biased coins. Coin $i$ lands on heads with probability $p_i$ which comes from a uniform prior probability distribution over $[0, 1]$. At times $t = 1, 2, ..., k$ I must select one of the coins to flip (Assume k > n). What strategy would give a maximal expected number of heads over the k flips?

This problem seems so deceptively simple... You obviously need to make some trade-off between flipping the coin that has given the best return so far and trying out others to see if they're better. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use the weighted majority algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Majority_Algorithm).

Comment: How do I use that? Can you explain?

Comment: I think you are looking for the Gittins index, though I wikipedia-ed the term and it did not obviously describe the problem you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the multiplicative weights algorithm (also known as weighted majority, boosting [in machine learning], and probably other names as well). See [this lecture](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~jenn/courses/F10/material/notes_1020.pdf) for example, section 2.